# Is there any open source text analysis library for PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, text, analysis

I am looking for a PHP library which does more or less the same thing as this webpage: http://textalyser.net/

I know that there are popular libraries in python and java, but I am looking for a PHP version. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you by any chance interested in static analysis of PHP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

As far as I'm aware there's isn't one, or at least not a well-known / 
well-distributed one.

### Long Answer

The closes de-facto code I've come across is  [php-text-statistics](http://code.google.com/p/php-text-statistics/) by [Dave 
Child](http://www.addedbytes.com/) (since the [PEAR version](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Statistics) has been unmaintained for *years*) but 
that only takes care of readability and sentence, word and syllable counting. 
Any other data you'd have to get yourself with [`count_chars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php), 
[`str_word_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), [`substr_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), 
[`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and the like. And of course some math 
skills to calculate all the percentages.

That said, I'm not sure *exactly* what is it you'd want the library to do, or 
what http://textalyser.net/ does...
(I mean what *is* a stoplist anyway? Or an exhaustive polyword phrase, for that 
matter...?)

Comment: I second that, in fact its looking like your only more or less solid option!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old question...
Anyways, if you want to find the the similarity between two given strings, PHP ha a built-in function `similar_text`.

**SYNTAX:**   `similar_text ($first, $second, &$percent = null);`

```
//*Find the similarity/difference between two strings in percentage
$pc = 0;
similar_text('You rock!', 'I Rock too!!',$pc);
print $pc;
```

**OUTPUT:**  `57.142857142857`

As noted above this value is the percentage two strings are similar.

> Note: This function is case sensitive

```
$pc = 0;
similar_text('you', 'YOU',$pc);
print $pc;
```

will give 0!

Two more such functions I came across are:
Levenshtein Distance & Soundex

For more information please check [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for a similiar thing at the moment and the options I have found so far are to make use of the Zend Lucene Search functionality.

http://www.opendocs.net/php/zend/ZendFramework-0.1.5/documentation/end-user/pl/zend.search.extending.html

or alternatively to look into the Open Calais API. http://www.opencalais.com/ (from Thomson Reuters)

I have yet to explore either option in any depth but I think that there might be some mileage in them for building dynamic links or hyper(con)textualising web pages.